# Copying and pasting multiple Excel files with python and win32com

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

Please excuse me as I am really new to this. I got a folder of .csv files which I am trying to format for analysis. The point is to delete some rows and then format one column using the text formula and the copying the values of that formula to either a new or same column so it can be read with another app as text. The logic continues the following pattern. First I convert the files to .xlsx in a loop using glob. Next I define the worksheets using openpyxl inside that loop:

```
wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
sheet2 = wb2.worksheets[0]
```

After this I use the following loop inside the other loop to copy and paste an excel formula into a new column:

```
i = "=TEXT(D2:D20,432)"
for row, celo in enumerate(list(sheet2.columns)[4]):
    celo.value = i
```

Everything works fine until I get to the win32com part:

```
    exc = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    exc.Visible = 1
    source = exc.Workbooks.Open()
    exc.Range("E1:E20").Select()
    exc.Selection.Copy()
    exc.Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste=constants.xlPasteValues
```

Code works fine for one excel file that has its path defined but I have no idea how to use the `source = exc.Workbooks.Open()` to open a folder full of csv/xlsx files and paste the special values to every excel file in that folder. I tried using wb2,ws2, sheet2 in the parenthesis but nothing. I have very limited vba knowledge (started today). I am trying to do all of this in Python.